# sheet.appendRow() sporadically fails silently and results in an empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using google-apps-script from google-spreadsheet,  I'm trying to fetch some hundreds of rows of data using fetchUrl and paste them into my sheet using sheet.appendRow.

Fetching data and splitting to arrays are OK. But appending them to a sheet row by row ocasionally fails without any errors and resulting in empty rows.

Here's quite simple example to recreate the problem.

```
function appendTest() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sSheet.getSheets()[2]);
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      sheet.appendRow([i, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  }
}
```

About 5 or 10 rows, differs time to time, become empty.
Inserting Utilities.sleep() seems to be not working, either.

Does anybody have any idea to get rid of this situation?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've tried a few times and cannot reproduce the error, seems to work flawlessly. Temporary server issue perhaps?

Comment: I can not reproduce this either. Even though appendRow should not be used like this, it should not fail either. Is there anyone editing the spreadsheet while the code is running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use batch writing to the sheet like this

```
function appendTest() {
  var target = new Array()
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sSheet.getSheets()[2]);
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      target.push(['some data','in some columns','bla bla']);
  }
sheet.getRange(sSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues(target);
}
```

Note that if you think the sheet will be too 'short' you could append empty rows in the loop as well.

**EDIT :** following Michael pertinent answer, it would be a much better idea to add the necessary rows using `sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getMaxRows(), target.length)`

Comment: sorry, I didn't try, I was just suggesting a better approach where no row can be left over ...

Comment: Sure, there would be more efficient ways for a user to append a block of data. I was thinking in a broader context that the OP's function may demonstrate a concurrency problem with appendRow() - the documentation suggests that appendRow() should be ideal when concurrency might be an issue. But as I commented, the OP's function worked fine for me (as a demonstration of appendRow() atomicity, not as a demonstration of best coding practices).

Comment: Although I cannot reproduce the situation today, as I read Michael's post and Serge's code, I have changed my code to bulk-insert data by setValues().  It works flawlessly and mucha fast. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If you are happy with one of the answer then please consider accepting it

Comment: I am not  appending the row inside the for loop, I just have one row to be appended based on the function call. But I have 44 columns to be given values in a row. The sheet.appendRow still fails. Please help

Answer (score 4):

Using appendRow inside a loop is flaky and not best practice. Please see:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/y0E9PB_VTJw

for a discussion of this issue.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the tip ;-) I updated my code using your ref. suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. Url have changed: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/y0E9PB_VTJw

Answer (score 2):

Just a small comment: 
I use appendRow in a loop, appending maybe up to 30 rows at a time.    The script has been used daily for about a week now.

The interesting part is that during testing of the script, when I set it to append about 100 rows, then I too saw rows missing.  But after a simple manual refresh of the destination spreadsheet, I saw no missing rows.  So I took it that the rows were in fact appended, but that the bug? lies in their display.