# Apps script inserts new row and values into a Google Sheet. However, it somehow skips rows if you submit too fast

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a server side apps script that inserts a new row into a Google sheet, and then adds data to corresponding columns.  Here is a short code snippet of what it does:

```
//check to see what is the last row of the sheet
var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();


//then, insert a new row after the last detected row
sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);

//then, set current work row to last_row + 1, then do some adding data. 
//Here, we add a current_timedate Date object that was created earlier.
var current_row = last_row + 1;
var current_timedate_cell = 'A' + current_row;
sheet.getRange(current_timedate_cell).setValue(current_timedate);
```

This is all pretty standard stuff.  However, I noticed if I call the function that does all this pretty quickly from the front end interface (I have another client side javascript / html interface that calls the server side javascript function with onClick method on a button), it starts to skip rows.  There also seems to be some bizarre concurrency issues.  Some rows actually have partial data inserted, but only for checkboxes that I'm adding.  None of the other stuff gets added.  I can't tell if there is mixing of data between rows since all of the data is repeated.  So, I can't tell if row 2's column H is now in row 3's column H, etc...  To be fair, I am inserting one LARGE cell per row up to the 50k character limit.  So, each row is probably close to 50k.  That could be causing these issues

Can anyone provide some insights?  I know Google Sheets is not supposed to be a relational database with ACID integrity and concurrent performance.  But, I thought it would do a better job of handling 50kb inserts.

I've tried SpreadsheetApp.flush().  I'm somewhat aware of the rate limitations, and perhaps that might be it.  I'm sometimes doing the inserts at a rate of about 3 inserts / second.  I'll go double check quota rate limits.  But, 3 / second doesn't seem incredibly high.

Expected results: all data requested to be inserted is inserted
Actual results: lots of skipped rows on faster insert rates

I'm doing all of this in a try / catch block, and so far I'm not getting any errors thrown.  If there is an error thrown, I both log it in Logger and email it to myself via the MailApp.

Comment: Have you tried using `appendRow()` rather than `insertRowAfter()` ?

Comment: That seems interesting.  It looks like it may handle atomicity.  Nice!  I'll give it a try and report back in a few.  Much thanks!

Comment: Looks like appendrows has similar issues.  see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510797/sheet-appendrow-sporadically-fails-silently-and-results-in-an-empty-row

Comment: Hi ross, would love to be able to upvote your comment.  But, I'm still new and lowly.  That definitely did the trick for me.  I can now add 10 rows in quick succession with no weird issues.  It looks like all of the concurrency stuff has been solved for me.  The only big thing now is for me to re-write my entire code.  I have to still figure out how to add or remove checkboxes now using the appendrow method, which may not work out.

Comment: I've added this as an actual answer instead of the comment, as for the checkboxes try to get it working and if you can't crack it I'm sure someone here will be able to.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to add it as an answer instead of comment since it answered the question:

Use `appendRow()` instead of `insertRowAfter()` for this purpose.